# When is target of a button (UIButton) not "self"?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, action

I am a beginner of iOS and in the programming tutorials when adding button programmatically, target is always set to self, and in that controller where it is being created, an action (`IBAction`) is written. Or through the interface builder, target is set to File's Owner.

My question is that in what scenario (an example would be great) that target is not self.

One scenario I can think of is when in a class's (which is not a `ViewController`) method a button is created depending on a condition, since that class is not a `ViewController`, when initializing an object of that class, a reference to the current `ViewController` would be set and that will be used as target where action is defined for the button if it appears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can direct the selector to any target – the reason why ordinarily, `self` is the target is because it is quite normal to instantiate a UIButton/UIBarButtonItem in code, so a lot of tutorials include the implementation the selector references in the same class.

You could, for example, make a class that when instantiated in your View Controller is designed to only handle these button invocation actions:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "OtherObject.h"

@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) OtherObject *other;

@end

@implementation SomeViewController

@synthesize other;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [someButton addTarget:other action:@selector(someMethodInOther) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:someButton];

    UIButton *anotherButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [anotherButton addTarget:other action:@selector(anotherMethodInOther) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:anotherButton];
}

@end
```

IBAction lets you tell Interface Builder that the method implementation can be connected through your xib/storyboard.